Is $\frac{10^{\left\lfloor \log _{10}x\right\rfloor }}{x}\left\lfloor \frac{x}{10^{\left\lfloor \log _{10}x\right\rfloor }}\right\rfloor >\frac{1}{2}$
I am trying to prove that the sequence defined for any $x>0$ by : $u_{0}=\left\lfloor 
\frac{x}{10^{\left\lfloor \log _{10}x\right\rfloor }}\right\rfloor
10^{\left\lfloor \log _{10}x\right\rfloor },$ $u_{n}=u_{n-1}+%
\left\lfloor \frac{x-u_{n-1}}{10^{\left\lfloor \log
_{10}\left( x-u_{n-1}\right) \right\rfloor }}\right\rfloor
10^{\left\lfloor \log _{10}\left( x-u_{n-1}\right)
\right\rfloor }$ converges to $x$.
All I have now to do is to prove that $\frac{10^{\left\lfloor \log
_{10}x\right\rfloor }}{x}\left\lfloor \frac{x}{10^{\left\lfloor \log
_{10}x\right\rfloor }}\right\rfloor >\frac{1}{2}$, to deduce by induction
that $x-u_{n}<\frac{x}{2^{n+1}}.$
So any help please ?
This is the graph of $\frac{10^{\left\lfloor \log _{10}x\right\rfloor }}{x}\left\lfloor \frac{x}{10^{\left\lfloor \log _{10}x\right\rfloor }}\right\rfloor$


For all real numbers $y \ge 1$ is
$$
\frac{\lfloor y \rfloor}{y} > \frac{\lfloor y \rfloor}{\lfloor y \rfloor + 1} = 1 - \frac{1}{\lfloor y \rfloor + 1} \ge \frac 12 \, .
$$
Applying this to
$$
y = \frac{x}{10^{\lfloor \log_{10}x \rfloor}} \ge 1
$$
gives the desired estimate.
Remark: For $x = r \cdot 10^k$ with $1 \le r < 2$ and positive integers $k$ is $y = r$ and $\lfloor y \rfloor/y = 1/r$, this shows that the lower bound $1/2$ is best possible.

Thank you so much
